# KeyError when running a Scrapy spider in Python 3.11.2

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to run a Scrapy spider in Python 3.11.2, but I keep getting a KeyError with the following traceback:

raise KeyError(f"Spider not found: {spider_name}")
KeyError: 'Spider not found: Myspider'

I've tried running the spider using the command scrapy crawl myspider from the folder level that contains the file scrapy.cfg.

Here is my code:

```
import scrapy

class ebook_scrapy(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "myspider"
    start_urls = ['https://books.toscrape.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
      print(["OurRespons!"])
        print(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an indentation in your code error in the parse method and you this command to run the crawler it should work. `scrapy crawl myspider`.  I guess you are typing `myspider` wrong (`MySpider`)

```
import scrapy

class ebook_scrapy(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "myspider"
    start_urls = ['https://books.toscrape.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
      print(["OurRespons!"])
      print(response)
```